# Ubuntu 16.04 server ports are closing on their own

Tags: networking, server, apache2, 16.04, postfix

I am running squirrelmail, apache2, and postfix on Ubuntu 16.04 server edition. The server works fine, but if I don't use it for about an hour port 80 and 25 become closed for anyone trying to connect using my public ip.

Then if I reboot, everything will work fine for about an hour. All my debian servers still work so I know the problem is with Ubuntu and not my router.

Comment: I have purged ufw and iptables.

Comment: I presume that you mean that you purged the iptables userspace tools and not that you deleted the entire kernel since iptables itself is of course a core kernel component responsible for *all* IP handling and routing on the system. Really it's hard to diagnose the issue without more details, have you even checked to make sure that the daemons are still running, what about checking the webserver logs/error logs, mailserver logs/error logs, also the main system log files like /var/log/syslog etc they may give clues. How does your apache and postfix configuration look etc?

Comment: Yes, postfix and apache2 are both still running and I'm going to assume that the configuration files are ok because squirrelmail still works fine after it goes down, but only by local ip not public.

Comment: I have also check my arp, dns, and ip stack everything looks fine. I can ping and resolve host names correctly. I know my router is functioning properly because all my other servers work using the same public ip.

Comment: When I ping from the server to 8.8.8.8, the first ping is ridiculously slow, about 2000ms. While all the rest are less then 30ms.

Comment: That is strange, do you get similar symptoms if you instead ping into the server from a machine on a different network? This initial delay applies if you try pinging other addresses too? Does it make a difference if you try pinging say 208.67.222.222 then right after that immediately ping 8.8.8.8 does the initial delay still happen? It's sounding oddly like a routing issue and slow ARP or an address conflict seems suspect here. Is the machine IPv6 capable try ping6 see if results is the same their IPv6 addresses are 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2620:0:ccc::2.

Comment: I do not get the delay if I ping from outside to the server. I originally thought that it could be an arp problem as well. So I tried adding the correct static arp entries, but it didn't make a difference. I also completely disabled ipv6 to make sure it wasn't the issue. Right now I set up a new Ubuntu server 16.04 machine, and the only thing I installed on it is apache. I'm going to give it about 2 hours and see if it has the same problem. This way we can narrow down the issue even further. I will let you know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with my router not getting the correct arp information. I fixed the problem by giving my router static arp entries.